# Android Studio TextWatcher attributes names issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-textwatcher

I'm actually following a class on creating my first android application with Android Studio. I need to use TextWatcher, and obtain something like this :

```
mNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
       
   }
 
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
 
   }
 
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       // This is where we'll check the user input
   }
});
```

But instead, I'm obtaining this :

```
mNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
 
            }
 
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
 
            }
 
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
 
            }
        });
```

As you can see, I don't have `start, count and after` but `i, i1 and i2`. The class explains that it's an issue, and how to fix it : by downloading the source code of the android version I'm using with the SDK Manager. I've downloaded the version I clicked on when creating my project, but it's not solving my issue.

I really hope someone can help me, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

it is just naming!

pay attention to the order of `start`, `before`, and `count`. the `i`, `i1`, and `i2` variables represent those in the same order.
for example, for `beforeTextChanged` the `i`, `i1` and `i2` are:

```
i=>start
i1=>count
i2=>after
```

you even can change the `i`,`i1`, and `i2` with any other names especially, `start`, `count`, and `after`.

Comment: Oh ok thank you! Because I saw that for everyone the names were start, before and count by default, and not for me haha, this is okay or is there a manipulation to do to get it right?
Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: No, it's not a big deal. It is the auto-generated name by the android studio. I suggest you change them to any name that makes sense to you. I'll be glad if you found this answer helpful, vote it up

Comment: alright, thank you very much! I did, have a nice day!